# jquery UI tabs and Datatables making multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables to display 4 separate and dynamic tables on 4 tabs using jquery. Everything works but the problem I am having is that upon clicking on each respective tab, datatables makes 4 ajax calls at the same time (viewed via firebug) which is causing lag for the selected tab/table.

I'm not sure were or why it's firing for each of the tabs - any help is apperciated

html for the first two table tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Instructions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Supervisors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Credit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Historical</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5">Agency</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a></li>
</ul>
  <div id="tabs-2">
  <asp:Table ID="displayTable1"  class="display displayTable" runat="server">
   <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="Gray" TableSection="TableHeader">  
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>SuperVisorStatus</asp:TableHeaderCell>    
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>CreditUpdates</asp:TableHeaderCell>    
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>SupervisorStatusDate</asp:TableHeaderCell>    
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>CreditUpdatesDate</asp:TableHeaderCell>   
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Selltokey</asp:TableHeaderCell>  
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>customer</asp:TableHeaderCell>

  </asp:Table>
 </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
  <asp:Table ID="displayTable2"  class="display displayTable" runat="server">
   <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="Gray" TableSection="TableHeader">  
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>SuperVisorStatus</asp:TableHeaderCell>    
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>CreditUpdates</asp:TableHeaderCell>    
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>SupervisorStatusDate</asp:TableHeaderCell>    
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>CreditUpdatesDate</asp:TableHeaderCell>   
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Selltokey</asp:TableHeaderCell>  
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>customer</asp:TableHeaderCell>
  </asp:Table>
 </div>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "<b>Whoops!  We've experienced some sort of error!</b><br> <br>Please contact <a href="me@a.b">me!</a>" +
                        " with specific details" 
                    );
                });
            },
        "activate": function(event, ui) {
            if ($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active')  === 1) {
                jaxUrl = "tableAjax.aspx?type=supervisor&json=yes";
            } else if ($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active')  === 2) {
                jaxUrl = "tableAjax.aspx?type=credit&json=yes";
            } else if ($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active')  === 3) {
                jaxUrl = "tableAjax.aspx?type=historical&json=yes";
            } else {
                jaxUrl = "";
            }

            var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
            $('table.display').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": jaxUrl,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 200], [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 200]],
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "bDestroy": true
            });
        }
    });
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused due to your initialization call :

```js
$('table.display').dataTable( {
...
```

which will run for *each* table every time a tab is shown / activated. You are simply forgetting to target the table on the tab there is about to get activated only. Use :

```js
var index=$("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');
$('table.display').eq(index-1).dataTable( {
...
```

-- instead. By that you will address the right table, and that table only.

Note : Completely untesed since I cannot reproduce your ASP-scenario.

Comment: Firstly, sorry for the delayed response.

Secondly, thanks so much for answering. Your solution works and now the page is running amazingly. I really appreciate your help.